# cakephp fetch from among multiple values in single column

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm using cakePHP 2.3 to build an application with a restaurant database. Now, the person before me has saved restaurant details in a table called 'locations' which has a row for cuisine which has multiple values in one column, like 1 location can have chinese, indian, korean etc.

If I fetch data using post and retrieve from the column using exact value like this:

```
$restaurant_cuisine = $this->params['url']['restaurant_cuisine'];   
$data = $this->Location->findAllByCuisine($restaurant_cuisine);
```

Then it is displaying value only if it exactly matches...eg:If i post "north indian,chinese,mughlai" then it matches it word to word. 
I want a query where I can search Chinese and all restaurants having chinese display even if they have other cuisines.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

you can't use magic find type because they don't allow LIKE conditions. You must use full syntax:

```
$data = $this->Location->find(
    'all', 
     array(
         'conditions' => array('Location.cuisine LIKE' => "%$restaurant_cuisine%")
     ));
```

Comment: Hi! That worked like a charm :) 
One more thing though, if the column has values store like this "north indian,chinese,mughlai", I want that non adjacent cuisines should be searchable too...like if i receive "'north indian' 'mughlai'" in the posted data, it should still show even though there's chinese in between. Basically is there a command to select multiple partial values from a string in the column?

Comment: no, (not so easily, I mean). You'd better create a new table called couisines and a model called Cuisine and put it in relationship with Location  (Location HABTM Cuisine and vice versa)